# Using abind with arrays of mode list

Tags: r, arrays

I have an array of mode list e.g. as created from the following tapply code:

```
my.data <- data.frame(expand.grid(species = c(1:3), year = c(1972:2000), VA = c(1:10), SA=c(1:3)))

test <- tapply(my.data$SA, list(my.data$species,my.data$year, my.data$VA), as.character)

mode(test)
#> [1] "list"

is.array(test)
#> [1] TRUE
```

How do I use abind to add an additional dimension? Using abind will give me an error because of mode "list"

```
test2 <- abind(test, test[,,1])
#> Error in abind(test, test[, , 1]) : 
#>   can only supply one list-valued argument for ...
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a list to `abind`, so just put `test` and `test[,,1]` in a list and pass that:

```
dim(test)
#> [1]  3 29 10

library(abind)
test2 <- abind(list(test, test[,,1]))

dim(test2)
#> [1]  3 29 11
```

However, this may not be the result you are looking for, since in your original 3-D array, each "cell" is actually a list containing a length-3 character vector. There may be no way around this if the character vectors in your real data are of different lengths, but if they are all the same length then the best thing to do would be to construct a 4-D array like this:

```r
test <- array(unlist(test), dim = c(dim(test), length(test[[1]])))
dimnames(test) <- list(element = 1:3, year = 1972:2000, VA = 1:10, species = 1:3)

dim(test)
#> [1]  3 29 10  3
```

Now it will also be much easier to keep track of which dimension you are working with.

For example:

```
test[,,VA = 3,]
#> , , species = 1
#> 
#>        year
#> element 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983
#>       1 "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#>       2 "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
#>       3 "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
#>        year
#> element 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995
#>       1 "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#>       2 "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
#>       3 "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
#>        year
#> element 1996 1997 1998 1999 2000
#>       1 "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#>       2 "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
#>       3 "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
#> 
#> , , species = 2
#> 
#>        year
#> element 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983
#>       1 "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#>       2 "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
#>       3 "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
#>        year
#> element 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995
#>       1 "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#>       2 "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
#>       3 "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
#>        year
#> 
#> ...etc
```

If you wanted to add an extra element to the "element" dimension you could do

```
test2 <- abind(list(test, test[1,,,]), along = 1)

test2
#> , , 1
#> 
#>   1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984
#> 1 "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#> 2 "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
#> 3 "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
#>   "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#>   1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997
#> 1 "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#> 2 "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
#> 3 "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3" 
#>   "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
#>   1998 1999 2000
#> 1 "1"  "1"  "1" 
#> 2 "2"  "2"  "2" 
#> 3 "3"  "3"  "3" 
#>   "1"  "1"  "1" 
#>
#> ... etc
```

Comment: Thank you Allan, in the real dataset actually each cell has a different character vector length, and the additional dimension i need to add is the merge of the two original dimensions (e.g. each cell of test[,,3] = c(test[,,1], test[,,2]). So i am still not able to find a solution...

Comment: @Miguel if you just want to concatenate the vectors in each cell of `test[,,1]` and `test[,,2]` into the slice `test[,,3]` you can do `test[,,3] <- mapply(c, test[,,1], test[,,2], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`